# Does regularly playing music to cows increase their appetite?

Tags: music, cows

The Kobe Beef Marketing & Distribution Promotion Association [says](http://www.kobe-niku.jp/english/contents/faq/) :

> There may well be some farms rearing low numbers of cattle who are
>   doing things bordering on this. But, this does not mean that these
>   rearing methods are all standards for producing prime Kobe Beef. For
>   example, **if you make it a custom of playing music at feeding time,
>   then the cows as a conditioned reflex know that it's feeding time just
>   by hearing the music, and this, it is said, increases their
>   appetite.** However, the affect of music improving meat quality has
>   not yet been proved. There is also the theory that beer is useful in
>   improving cows' appetites. Actually, however, it can be said that
>   there have been almost no cases of cows being raised on beer. And,
>   massage, too, is considered to be useful in lowering cows' stress
>   because of the close, physical contact it provides and in indirectly
>   helping to improve the quality of the meat. Once again, however,
>   massage itself neither softens meat nor increases the amount of
>   marbling.

Does regularly playing music to cows increase their appetite?

Comment: I can only give you a very poorly controlled result from few cattle as this wasn't an experiment. We kept a radio on during the day so human voices wouldn't spook them. They did not seem to eat any more than other calves at feed time. They did sometimes linger around the radio which was near food, and that could induce eating. I always felt that was just 'persistent availability' at work but who knows.